# Codeigniter: no records has been saved in mysql database after clicking submit button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently working on codeigniter. I want to insert records in database. But when I click submit button, the records in database has not been saved.

Please help me. Thank you.

Here is my view (payroll_add.php):

```
<?php echo form_open('home/saveEmpPayroll',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Employee</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <?php echo form_dropdown('empid', $dropdown, '', 'class="form-control" id="empid"'); ?>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Basic Salary</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="emp_salary" name="emp_salary" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Total Bus Income for the week</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="total_income" name="total_income" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">SSS Bracket</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control" id="emp_SSS">
            <option value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['SSS_bracket'])) {
                echo $_POST ['$SSS_bracket'];}?>"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">SSS Deduction</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" id="SSSdeduction" name="SSSdeduction" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Philhealth Bracket</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <select class="form-control" id="emp_Philhealth">
                <option value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['Philhealth_bracket'])) {
                    echo $_POST ['$Philhealth_bracket'];}?>"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Philhealth Deduction</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" id="Philhealthdeduction" name="Philhealthdeduction" class="form-control" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Type of Allowance</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="Meal Allowance">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Total Allowance</label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" id="emp_allowance" name="emp_allowance" class="form-control" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="emp_submit" id="emp_submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is my controller: (home.php)

```
public function viewAddEmployeePayrollForm() { 
        $this->load->model('Model_payroll');
        $data = array();
        $data['dropdown'] = $this->Model_payroll->get_dropdown();
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('imports/menu');
        $this->load->view('payroll/payroll_add', $data);
    }

public function saveEmpPayroll() {
        $this->load->model('Model_payroll');
        $p = new Model_payroll();
        $p->emp_id = $this->input->post('empid');
        $p->basic_salary = $this->input->post('emp_salary');
        $p->meal_allowance = $this->input->post('emp_allowance');
        $p->SSS_bracket = $this->input->post('emp_SSS');
        $p->SSS_deduction = $this->input->post('SSSdeduction');
        $p->Philhealth_bracket = $this->input->post('emp_Philhealth');
        $p->Philhealth_deduction = $this->input->post('Philhealthdeduction');
        $p->bus_income = $this->input->post('total_income');
        $result = $p->saveEmployeePayroll();
        if (!$result) {
            echo mysqli_error($result);
        }
        else {
            redirect('home/goViewEmpPayroll', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Here is my model (model_payroll.php):

```
<?php

class Model_payroll extends CI_Model {

    public $emp_id;
    public $basic_salary;
    public $meal_allowance;
    public $SSS_bracket;
    public $SSS_deduction;
    public $Philhealth_bracket;
    public $Philhealth_deduction;
    public $ot_rate;
    public $ot_total;
    public $bus_income;

    public function getEmployeePayroll() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('tbl_payroll');
        $this->db->join('employees', 'employees.empnum = tbl_payroll.emp_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function addEmployeePayroll() {
        $this->db->where('emp_id', $this->emp_id);
        $query = $this->db->insert('tbl_payroll', $this);
        return $query;
    }

    public function saveEmployeePayroll() {
        if (isset($this->emp_id)) {
            $query = $this->updateEmployeePayroll();
        }
        else {
            $query = $this->addEmployeePayroll();
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function updateEmployeePayroll() {
        $this->db->where('emp_id', $this->emp_id);
        $query = $this->db->update('tbl_payroll', $this);
        return $query;
    }

    public function get_dropdown() {
        $result = $this->db->select('empnum, name')->get('employees')->result_array();
        $dropdown = array();
        foreach($result as $r) {
            $dropdown[$r['empnum']] = $r['name'];
        }
        return $dropdown;
    }
}
```

But there's nothing records has been saved in mysql database after clicking submit button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is "updateEmployeePayroll"

Comment: I've done putting the "updateEmployeePayroll".

Comment: With respect -  you don't understand the basics of codeigniter. Do the tutorial in the codeigniter manual so you will understand how to call model methods, etc.

Comment: yes please go through a CRUD tutorial and you will be able to work fast, just an advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your method

```
public function updateEmployeePayroll() {
    $this->db->where('emp_id', $this->emp_id);
    $query = $this->db->update('tbl_payroll', $this);
    return $query;
}
```

$query = $this->db->update('tbl_payroll', $this);

$this contain CI data as well. please do not use like that please see below for example.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

```
$this->db->update();

Generates an update string and runs the query based on the data you supply. You can pass an array or an object to the function. Here is an example using an array:

$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
            );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data); 

// Produces:
// UPDATE mytable 
// SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}'
// WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But this is not the one that I've looking for. I'm looking for a code that will save records in mysql database after clicking a submit button.

Comment: "But when I click submit button, the records in database has not been saved."

Can you clarified where is not working?

It can be from

html -> nothing happen when click submit - page not submit?
controller (saveEmpPayroll)- > do you prepare data to save correctly?
Model (updateEmployeePayroll) -> I can see you have issue when you call $this->db->update()

Answer (score 0):

```
You must have to form_validation:

    public function saveEmpPayroll() {
           if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->load->model('Model_payroll');
            $p = new Model_payroll();
            $p->emp_id = $this->input->post('empid');
            $p->basic_salary = $this->input->post('emp_salary');
            $p->meal_allowance = $this->input->post('emp_allowance');
            $p->SSS_bracket = $this->input->post('emp_SSS');
            $p->SSS_deduction = $this->input->post('SSSdeduction');
            $p->Philhealth_bracket = $this->input->post('emp_Philhealth');
            $p->Philhealth_deduction = $this->input->post('Philhealthdeduction');
            $p->bus_income = $this->input->post('total_income');
            $result = $p->saveEmployeePayroll();
            if (!$result) {
                echo mysqli_error($result);
            }
            else {
                redirect('home/goViewEmpPayroll', 'refresh');
            }
           }
else{
        redirect('controller/viewAddEmployeePayrollForm');
}
        }
```